# Does fast bcp replicate in sybase sql statement replication?

Tags: sybase

Is it possible to replicate fast bcp using sql statement replication in sybase?

Answer (score 2):

No. Fast BCP is an unlogged operation.  Sybase Replication Server relies on scans of the Transaction log for data to be replication.  The Rep Agent thread scans the transaction log in the Primary Database (PDB) for commits.  Once a committed transaction is found in the Transaction log, the SQL statements are forwarded to the Replication Server.  If an action is not logged, like Fast BCP, then no entry is created in the transaction log, and therefore it can't be replicated.

Slow BCP transactions will replicate, as Slow BCP is a logged operation.

In Sybase ASE 15.7, Fast-logged BCP has been introduced, but I am not sure about whether that is supported for Replication yet.

Comment: @Gardner, I am not satisfied with the relation between SQL statement replication in Sybase and non-logged operation. As per http://infocenter.sybase.com, In SQL statement replication, Replication Server receives the SQL statement that modified the primary data, rather than the individual row changes from the transaction log.

Comment: Just expanded my answer a bit.  Although you properly state how Replication works, it relies on the Transaction log, so operations that are unlogged will not replicate.

Comment: found non-logged (select into) can be replicated in warmstandy configuration using SQL statement replication.                   http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32518.1571/doc/html/san1292613434328.html

Comment: Yes, but the fact remains that BCP doesn't create a SQL statement to replicate.